# What is the best way to extract list of values that meet some condition from 2d list python

Tags: python

I have a 2d list

```
grid = [[10,13,17],[3,5,1],[13,1,12]]
```

I want to get the position of all ones in it in the form of list of tuples

```
my_list = [[(i,j) for i in list_ if i == 1] for j,list_ in enumerate(grid)]
```

But my output is the following

```
[[], [(1, 1)], ...]
```

How can I get rid of empty lists and redundant brackets? My expected output is

```
[(1, 2), (2, 1)]
```

Comment: The first one is at position (1, 2), the second one is at (2, 1). How do you get `[(1, 1), (1, 2)]`?

Comment: Convert to array and use `np.argwhere`. `grid = np.array([[10,13,17],[3,5,1],[13,1,12]])` and `list(map(tuple,np.argwhere(grid==1)))` and make your life easier

Comment: By the way, your (1,1) doesn't make sense

Comment: Yes, I should've used enumerate(list_) in the 1st case too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
grid = [[10,13,17],[3,5,1],[13,1,12]]
results = [(i, b) for b in range(len(grid)) for i, a in enumerate(grid[b]) if a == 1]
```

Output:

```
[(2, 1), (1, 2)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Under the assumption that your expected output is, well, wrong.

---

Consider using `numpy`.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[10,13,17],[3,5,1],[13,1,12]])                                                                       
>>> [tuple(x) for x in np.argwhere(a == 1)
[(1, 2), (2, 1)]
>>>
>>> a = np.array([[10,13,17],[1,5,1],[13,1,12]])                                                                       
>>> [tuple(x) for x in np.argwhere(a == 1)]                                                                              
[(1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 1)]
```

Alternatively, `list(map(tuple, np.argwhere(a == 1)))` provided by [Bazingaa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4932316/bazingaa) arrives at the same result.

Comment: For educational purpose, perhaps you can add my answer which I commented below the post too getting rid of the for loop and the list comprehension

Comment: @Bazingaa I edited it in, but there's no use in "getting rid of" the list comprehension's *loop syntax*, it's just as fast as `list` + `map`.

Comment: It could be a matter of personal choice. Both ways are equally good. I actually wanted to answer myself but some people here downvote for overkill reasons. So I just left a comment

Answer (score 1):

Remove the sub-list creation and use a [nested list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions):

```
grid = [[10, 13, 17], [3, 5, 1], [13, 1, 12]]
my_list = [(i, j) for j, list_ in enumerate(grid) for i, val in enumerate(list_) if val == 1]
print(my_list)
```

**Output**

```
[(2, 1), (1, 2)]
```